# Kill a child process from parent Bash process

Tags: bash, signals

Is it possible to use signals in order to kill a child process from parent  Bash process? 
Kind regards

Comment: Yes. Signals are sent with the `kill` command. Do you know the PID of the child process? Are you aware of the bash variable `$!`?

Comment: It is possible. Please expand the question to show your code and explain your goals so that we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

try something like: 
kill $(ps -s $$ -o pid=)

Reference:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes